# Date parameter in SQL Server stored procedure from ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I've written an SQL Server stored procedure that, amongst other things, accepts a `date` parameter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE data.addScore
    ... (some parameters),
    @testDate date
AS
```

On an ASP.NET page I have a textbox with a Calender Extender control (from the AJAX Toolkit) that allows the user to select a date; the date is stored in the textbox in the format `DD/MM/YYYY`. I have some code that is supposed to execute the stored procedure with the parameters, using the date value from the textbox:

```
cmd.Parameters["@testDate"].Value = Convert.ToDateTime(((TextBox)li.FindControl("date")).Text);
```

I know I can definitely get to the textbox's value using `((TextBox)li.FindControl("date")).Text`, but for the life of me I can't get it into a format that doesn't throw up one of a few errors, mainly 'Input string was not in the correct format'.

When I run the stored procedure directly on the server I usually bind the parameter like `@testDate = 'YYYYMMDD'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you don't store anything in the textbox using regional, ambiguous formats like dd/mm/yyyy. If you use an unambiguous format like YYYYMMDD, you're not going to have any issues. And if users are picking from a calendar control or something, it should be easy to separate the date you present to them from the date you pass to the database.

Comment: Point taken - thanks for your answer. I'd like to understand it all though - at present I have an `SqlDataSource` using the same textbox as a `ControlParameter` to a `date` field and it works perfectly. What am I doing wrong in my code behind that ASP.NET does correctly for it's own binding?

Comment: @Katstevens I don't know your whole setup, but it's likely that some layer is using US English for locale, or dateformat of m/d/y. The safest approach is to just always use unambiguous formats when passing string literals to the database, regardless of what you show users (though I suggest unambiguous formats there too).

Comment: At present I am using `Convert.ToDateTime` to get a `DateTime` object holding the date, and it is parsing it correctly. I thought passing this in to the database parameter would be the most unambiguous solution as it is not reliant on formatting. I get an error about converting a string to Int32 though - but I am using a date object! Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Textbox id="date" runat="Server"></asp:Textbox>

<cc1:CalendarExtender ID="calwhendate" runat="server" Enabled="true" Format="YYYYMMDD"
TargetControlID="date"></cc1:CalendarExtender>
```

Change your Ajax Calendar Control to your desired format